# Where is the root file system loaded from in alpine diskless mode

Tags: raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

When installing alpine linux in diskless mode ([described here](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installation)) where is the actual root file system stored?

According to the documentation in diskless mode:

> This means the entire operating system with all applications are first loaded into RAM and then only run from there.

I understand additional packages added by the user are installed by initramfs from APKs added by the user.  I'm wondering where the base OS root file system is stored.